# Imageview from phone galley

Tags: android, imageview

im trying to access and select an image from my phone galley onto my application imageView, using android. So far ive managed to set get to the galley and select the image i want to use, the only problem is that once ive selected the image i want i cant get it onto the imageview. the problem seems to be that ive got the imageview class seperate from my main class. ive checked and cant find a solution.

heres the code for the mediagalley class

public class MediaGallery extends Activity {
    public static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String path = getPath(selectedImage);

        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);


    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null,null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

    return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
}
```

}

and the main class code

```
case R.id.gallery_button:
            MediaGallery activ1 = new MediaGallery();
            Intent gallery = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, 1);
            activ1.onActivityResult(1, 1, gallery);
            break;
```

any help u gave give il be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

You have declared MediaGallery is another Activity.  Are you trying to show an ImageView on the same activity from which you select the button to launch the picker, or in a new activity?  If the former, put that onActivityResult code into your main class.  If the latter, then your main class should pass the Intent data to the MediaGallery class.